# Adding view count to external links on site

Tags: javascript, view, count

I want to create a gallery where the images link directly out to the website in a new window when clicked.

However I would also like a view (or click to be more descriptive) count to show overlayed on the image on hover.

How do I do about creating the link/view count? Since no page is actually loaded - only a link clicked?

On top of that I would also like to use a custom short URL service. Does anyone know one that is good and/or would have a solution to my problem?

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I've made a TODO list for you :)

1. [JS/AJAX] catch the click event and send a message to the server what was clicked
2. [PHP/ROR/Python/etc] store information in the DB (increment the clicked element counter)
3. [PHP/ROR/Python/etc] when page is loaded, retrieve counter values from DB and put them into the HTML
4. [JS] use counter values to display them over images

As for short URL services I like goo.gl .